# I am getting error when set duedate creating issue in jira

Tags: java, jira, jython, python-jira

This is my post function. I am working on jython scripting suite.

```
from java.util import Calendar    
from java.util import Date    
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor    
from com.atlassian.jira import ComponentManager    
from com.atlassian.jira.issue import Issue    
from java.sql import Timestamp    
import java    
import time

ts = long(time.time())    
issue.setDueDate(java.sql.Timestamp(ts))    
issue.store()
```

and this is what i am getting error

> Issue workflow initialization error: unable to find Issue created with
>   workflowId '10694'. Did the IssueCreateFunction run successfully on
>   workflow.initialize() ?

Comment: where did the issue come from? Have you read the error message or just pasted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an educated guess:

Your post function is modifying the issue before it has been created.
Have a look at the postfunctions in the create-transition:
The first one called should be "Creates the issue originally.". Place your own postfunction after it and it should work.